# How to add a relationship if the field value is 1 using hasmany() doctrine, php

Tags: doctrine

How to add a relationship if the field value is 1 using hasmany() doctrine, php
Example

I am having user table and user_locations with multiple  locations.

I need to get a record of non deleted locations from the user location table using user Obj.

By default the relation should be added to the records if the locations were not deleted from the user_locations

Note: The location will be deleted by the field is_deleted=1